# Listing directory names with Unicode symbols in them isn't working correctly

Tags: unicode, common-lisp, clisp, pathname

I'm trying to write to a file a list of all the sub-directories, but the unicode symbols in the sub-directory names get replaced by question marks. I'm using CLISP 2.49 on Windows XP.

Here is the short version of the code:

```
(let ((*pathname-encoding* (ext:make-encoding :charset 'charset:utf-8
                                              :line-terminator :dos)))
    (with-open-file (stream "folders.txt"
                     :direction :output
                     :if-exists :overwrite
                     :if-does-not-exist :create
                     :external-format (ext:make-encoding :charset 'charset:utf-8
                                                         :line-terminator :dos))
       (format stream "~A~&" (directory ".\\*\\"))))
```

Comment: We have a CLISP expert here on Stackoverflow who hopefully sees the question. So you may have luck. But usually such specialized questions might be more successfully asked on the mailing list for the specific implementation.

Answer (score 2):

### What you are doing wrong

You should be aware that [`*pathname-encoding*`](http://www.clisp.org/impnotes/encoding.html#path-enc) is a [SYMBOL-MACRO](http://www.ai.mit.edu/projects/iiip/doc/CommonLISP/HyperSpec/Body/mac_define-symbol-macro.html), not a variable.
As the note in the [CLISP](http://www.clisp.org) manual says,

> Reminder: You have to use [EXT:LETF/EXT:LETF*](http://www.clisp.org/impnotes/macros3.html#letf) for [SYMBOL-MACRO](http://www.ai.mit.edu/projects/iiip/doc/CommonLISP/HyperSpec/Body/mac_define-symbol-macro.html)s;
>   [LET/LET*](http://www.ai.mit.edu/projects/iiip/doc/CommonLISP/HyperSpec/Body/speope_letcm_letst.html) will not work!

So, what you need to do is

```
(ext:letf ((*pathname-encoding* charset:utf-8)) ...)
```

(the `line-terminator` mode of `*pathname-encoding*` is ignored anyway).

### Example

```
$ touch 'идиотский файл'
$ ls
идиотский файл
$ LANG=C ls
?????????????????? ????????
$ LANG=C clisp -q -norc 
> *pathname-encoding* 
#<ENCODING CHARSET:ASCII :UNIX>
> *default-file-encoding* 
#<ENCODING CHARSET:ASCII :UNIX>
> *terminal-encoding* 
#<ENCODING CHARSET:ASCII :UNIX>
> (letf ((*pathname-encoding* charset:utf-8))
    (with-open-file (o "foo" :direction :output :external-format charset:utf-8) 
      (format o "~A~%" (directory "*"))))
NIL
> (quit)
$ cat foo
(/home/sds/tmp/z/идиотский файл /home/sds/tmp/z/foo)
```

### Debugging your specific problem

Under no circumstances will CLISP print or return `?` instead of a character it cannot handle - it will signal an error (try to omit the one of the encoding specs and you will get an error `Invalid byte #xD0 in CHARSET:ASCII conversion` - either from `write` or from `directory`).

Therefore the problem is at the boundary:

- either the OS gives CLISP question marks instead of unicode (because it thinks that CLISP cannot handle i18n)
- or the files produced by CLISP are incorrectly saved by the low level OS layer
- or the tools you are using to view the files cannot display the unicode characters

(only the last option appears plausible).

What you could do is:

1. start with removing the encoding specs - do you get the conversion errors? examine the default encoding *places* (that's the fancy Lisp word for symbol macros like `*pathname-encoding*` &c)
2. make sure `*pathname-encoding*` is `utf-8` and try something like `(coerce (pathname-name (car (directory "*"))) 'list)` - in my example above I see `(#\CYRILLIC_SMALL_LETTER_I ...)`; do you see unicode chars like I do, or do you see `#\?`?
3. try `cygwin` (`ls`, `ls | od`, `ls > foo; cat foo | od`) to see whether it can capture the non-ascii characters.

Comment: I have modified the source code accordingly, but it still results in non English characters getting replaced with question marks.

Comment: @Hecatomb: what are you using to view the output file? are you sure it can show non-ASCII characters?

Comment: I use Notepad++ (I had no problems using it to display unicode characters before). Just to be sure I also opened it in HIEW (a hex editor, among other things...) and all of the question marks are in fact the same.

Comment: 1) I don't get errors when I try to run `(directory "*")` without setting the encoding places. *pathname-encoding*, *default-file-encoding* and *misc-encoding* default to CP1252. *terminal-encoding* defaults to CP437.
2) :
    [1]> *pathname-encoding*
    #<ENCODING CHARSET:CP1252 :DOS>
    [2]> (setf *pathname-encoding* charset:utf-8)
    #<ENCODING CHARSET:UTF-8 :UNIX>
    [3]> *pathname-encoding*
    #<ENCODING CHARSET:UTF-8 :UNIX>
    [4]> (coerce (pathname-name (car (directory "*"))) 'list)
    (#\? #\? #\? #\? #\? #\? #\_ #\? #\? #\? #\?)
3) Unfortunately I don't have cygwin installed